# AppleScript: Tell Google Chrome to activate/deactivate extension

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript, google-chrome

I want to have AppleScript activate/deactivate a plugin, using a keyboard command.

I have set the keyboard command in *Google Chrome > Settings > Extensions > Keyboard shortcuts* and it works when I do it manually. For this example, I'm using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

I've tried a few variants of this script.

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
tell application "Google Chrome" to key code u using {option down, shift down}
delay(1)
tell application "Google Chrome" to keystroke "r" using command down
```

The last past refreshes the window, and it works – but not the second line which is supposed to toggle the extension. Again, I can toggle the extension manually with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, but the script won't do it,

I also tried this:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to keystroke "u" using {option down, shift down}
```

Is the script actually supposed to work, making the problem reside somewhere else, or is there something wrong in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code instead.

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "u" using {option down, shift down}
delay(1)
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "r" using command down
```

I actually ran this applescript along with yours. First time I did not test yours seeing you called for a key code but gave it a keystroke value. When I ran your code, it gave me syntax errors(even with proper key code and keystroke values). When I ran my code, it compiles properly and runs the script as intended.

Comment: @Winterflags See update.